# Send a message from play's WebSocket immediately

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm attempting to send a message to websocket instantly after the connection is estabilished. But I don't know, where to put the code with the message send.

```
def ws = WebSocket.async[String] {
    val (out, channel) = {
        Concurrent.broadcast[String]
    }
    channel push "message"
    request =>
        (in, out)
}
```

I can see, that when I send the message to the channel before the `ws` method returns, the web client doesn't get the message. If I manage to run the code `channel push "message"` after the method `ws` returns, it works fine and I receive the message at the browser client. I can delay it by wrapping the `channel push "message"` in `Future{}`, starting with some `Thread.sleep()`.

But I hope, there some reliable, non-blocking solution...

Answer (score 2):

I see from the docs that `async` expects a lambda returning a `Promise[stuff]`.

Supposing that `(in, out)` gets implicitly converted to said Promise you could try to explicitly create the promise and register a listener like

```
def ws = WebSocket.async[String] {
    val (out, channel) = {
        Concurrent.broadcast[String]
    }
    request =>
      val p = Promise((in, out))
      p.onRedeem(_ => channel push "message")
      p
}
```

I'm no Play! expert here, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: I just had the same issue, and I confirm that your solution works ;) Except that `Promise` is replaced by `Future` in 2.2.X but the concept remains the same.